# Finding Duplicate Data Only Where Another Column Has a Different Value

Tags: mysql

I have a table full of IP addresses, member IDs and device IDs. I want to find accounts where the same IP address has been used by more than one member. However, because the table also records device IDs I can't just search for duplicate IP entries.

TABLE EXAMPLE

```
device_key      member_id       ip_address  
123452345       1               127.0.0.1       
2687924         1               127.0.0.1       
3983456         23              255.255.255.255  
4659824         876             255.255.255.255
54653787        90              1.1.1.1
```

I've tried this:

```sql
SELECT 
    member_id,
    ip_address, 
    COUNT(ip_address)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY ip_address
HAVING COUNT(ip_address) > 1
```

The above code will output both `127.0.0.1` and `255.255.255.255`. However I'm only interested in `255.255.255.255` as this IP is being used by more than one person. I can't figure out the correct code to only output this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ip_address, COUNT(DISTINCT member_id)
FROM table
GROUP BY ip_address
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) > 1;
```

If you want to get the actual member IDs who are using these IP addresses, you can do this:

```
SELECT ip_address, member_id
FROM table
WHERE ip_address IN (SELECT ip_address
                     FROM table
                     GROUP BY ip_address
                     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) > 1)
ORDER BY ip_address, member_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select ip_address
from (
  select distinct ip_address, member_id from t
) x
group by ip_address
having count(*) > 1
```